# How can i create a buffer without using malloc() in linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, malloc, buffer, free

How can I create a buffer in linux kernel without `malloc()` function (or `calloc()`) and clean buffer without `free()` function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use standard c library functions like `malloc()` or `calloc()` inside the kernel, The code you write in kernel links to the functionality provided by the kernel itself.

You can use **[kmalloc()](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-8-sect-1)** & then free it with **kfree()**.

Comment: Note that kernel memory can't be paged, so it's more expensive. Use it sparingly - only allocate small chunks, and few of them.